# When do you get disconnected from your current game in diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

When you go afk while in a game you'll get disconnected after some time. My question is how long is this time, and does it affect the time it needs to disconnect you if you either let the game run as it is, or pause it by pressing escape?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some research, and experimenting within my own game, and found out the following. I am not 100% sure of the accuracy of all of the above, it's to the best of my knowledge.

**Multiplayer**

- There is no disconnect timer.

**Singleplayer**

- There is a 30 minute disconnect timer.
- The timer is in effect in towns.
- The timer is in effect out of towns.
- The timer is in effect when unpaused.
- The timer is in effect when not paused.
- This mechanic has been complained about extensively, and might be changed in the future.

Most of the information I found can be found here: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5890100171

As well as here: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/7004458323

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it, you get disconnected after 30 minutes.